# Access a nested array of objects in nodejs, mysql and json

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, json, relational-database

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Progress_Category (
    categoryId int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (categoryId)
);
CREATE TABLE Progress_Skill (
    skillId int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    currentProgress int NOT NULL,
    `25` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `50` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `75` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    `100` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    categoryId int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (skillId),
    CONSTRAINT Constr_Progress_Skill_Skill_fk FOREIGN KEY Skill_fk (categoryId) REFERENCES Progress_Category(categoryId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE Progress_Message (
    messageId int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    message varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    messageDate DATE NOT NULL,
    skillId int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (messageId),
    CONSTRAINT Constr_Progress_Message_Message_fk FOREIGN KEY Message_fk (skillId) REFERENCES Progress_Skill(skillId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I have this query to retrieve all the data in a table:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Progress_Category AS pcat
        LEFT JOIN Progress_Skill AS ps
            ON pcat.categoryId = ps.catParentId
        LEFT JOIN Progress_Message AS pm
            ON ps.skillId = pm.skillParentId
```

For each skill of a category a new row of category will be created, with the respected skill. For each message of a skill a new row with the category and the skill will be created, with the respected message.

Query result:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| categoryId | catname   | skillId | skillname | currentProgress | 25   | 50    | 75     | 100   | catParentId | messageId | message                 | messageDate | skillParentId |
+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|          1 | Languages |       1 | Spanish   |             100 | Read | Write | Listen | Speak |           1 |         1 | Native language         | 2022-08-27  |             1 |
|          1 | Languages |       2 | English   |              85 | Read | Write | Listen | Speak |           1 |         2 | Learning since 2016     | 2022-08-27  |             2 |
|          1 | Languages |       2 | English   |              85 | Read | Write | Listen | Speak |           1 |         3 | Can speak almost fluent | 2022-08-27  |             2 |
|          2 | Projects  |    NULL | NULL      |            NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL | NULL                    | NULL        |          NULL |
|          3 | Ideas     |    NULL | NULL      |            NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL   | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL | NULL                    | NULL        |          NULL |
+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

In nodejs I use that query and the following code:

```
connection.query(myquery, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('----> Error with MySQL query in /api/showProgress: ' + err.message);
    }
    else{
        console.log('Query successful, results are being displayed.');
            
        var categories = [];
        for (let category in results) {
            if(categories.length > 0){
                for(let key in categories){
                    if(results[category].categoryId !== categories[key].Category.Id){
                        console.log("Category Id: " + results[category].categoryId + " Id already in the array: " + categories[key].Category.Id);
                        categories.push({
                            "Category" : [{
                                "Id" : results[category].categoryId,
                                "Name" : results[category].catname
                            }]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            categories.push({
                "Category" : [{
                    "Id" : results[category].categoryId,
                    "Name" : results[category].catname
                }]
            })
        }
    }
    response.send({"My progress" : categories});
});
```

The result I get:

```
Query successful, results are being displayed.
Category Id: 1 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 1 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 1 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 2 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 2 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 2 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 2 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
Category Id: 3 Id already in the array: undefined
```

So the problem is `categories[key].Category.Id`. I don't know how to access the property `Id` that belong to `Category` that is in the array.

The final idea is use that if so only one category is shown with an array of skills instead of a category, skill, same category, other skill:

Current:

```
{"My progress":[
    {
        "Category":[{
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Languages",
            "Skill":"asd"
        }]
    },
    {
        "Category":[{
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Languages",
            "Skill":"fgh"
        }]
    },
    {
        "Category":[{
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Languages",
            "Skill":"ijk"
        }]
    },
]}
```

Expected:

```
{"My progress":[
    {
        "Category":[
            {
                "Id":1,
                "Name":"Languages",
                "Skills":[{
                    "Name":"asd",
                    "Name":"fgh",
                    "Name":"ijk"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Id":2,
                "Name":"Projects",
                "Skills":[{
                    "Name":"123",
                    "Name":"456",
                    "Name":"789"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the expected result, changing almost everything:

```
{"My skills":[
    {
        "categoryId":1,
        "CategoryName":"Web development",
        "Subcategories":[
            {
                "parentId":1,
                "subcategoryId":1,
                "SubcategoryName":"Frontend",
                "Skills":[
                    "Sass",
                    "Css",
                    "Bootstrap",
                    "Figma"
                ]
            },
            {
                "parentId":1,
                "subcategoryId":2,
                "SubcategoryName":"Backend",
                "Skills":[
                    "Nodejs",
                    "Express",
                    "MySQL",
                    "PHP"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryId":2,
        "CategoryName":"Cybersecurity",
        "Subcategories":[
            {
                "parentId":2,
                "subcategoryId":3,
                "SubcategoryName":"Red team",
                "Skills":[
                    "curl",
                    "Sherlock",
                    "Wappalyzer",
                    "Burpsuite"
                ]
            },
            {
                "parentId":2,
                "subcategoryId":4,
                "SubcategoryName":"Blue team",
                "Skills":[
                    "Cloudfare"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Nodejs code:

```
connection.query(myquery, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('----> Error with MySQL query in /api/showSkills: ' + err.message);
    }
    else{
        console.log('Query successful, results are being displayed.');
        
        var mylist = [];
        var subcat = [];
        var lastPushedId = 0;
        for (let key in results){
            if(lastPushedId !== results[key].categoryId){
                for (let otherkey in results){
                    if(results[otherkey].subcatParentId === results[key].categoryId){
                        subcat.push({
                            'parentId': results[otherkey].subcatParentId,
                            'subcategoryId': results[otherkey].subcategoryId,
                            'SubcategoryName': results[otherkey].subcatname,
                            'Skills': results[otherkey].skills.split(',')
                        });
                    }
                }
                mylist.push({
                    'categoryId': results[key].categoryId,
                    'CategoryName': results[key].catname,
                    'Subcategories': subcat
                });
                subcat = [];
                lastPushedId = results[key].categoryId;
            }
        }
            response.send({"My skills" : mylist});
    }
});
```